# Create a dict of tuples from file

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I have a file that goes like this:

Limerick

8 A

5 B

Quintain (English)

0 A

0 B

I want to make it into a dict like this:

{'Limerick': ([8, 5], ['A', 'B']), 'Quintain (English)': ([0, 0], ['A', 'B'])}

So far, I've been able to get:

{'Limerick': [], 'Rondeau': [], 'Haiku': [], 'Quintain (English)': [], 'Sonnet': []},

but after that I don't know how to append the 8 A, 5 B etc. Tried getting index of where they start and stop but it doesn't seem like the IO of Python allows that.

Hypothetically, I was trying to add 8 A, 5 B into a list, then add 8, 5 and A, B into two list, then sort them out. But that doesn't seem possible/very ineffective.

My attempt(poem_form is what I managed to get):

```
def read_poetry_form_descriptions(poetry_forms_file):

    poem_file = open(poetry_forms_file, 'r')
    temp_poem, poem_form = {}, {}

    for line in poem_file:
        temp_poem[line.strip()] = ()
        poem_form.pop('', None)

    poem_file.close()

    for key in temp_poem:
        if key[0:3].isalpha():
            poem_form[key] = []

    print(poem_form)
```

Comment: How did you manage to get your version? Post your code so that we can find any errors.

Comment: @Selcuk Posted my code.

Comment: What you could try is, just like you used `.isaplha()`, you could use `.isdigit()` to get the numbers into a list.

Comment: So use another for loop with .isdigit()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to your issue.

```
def read_poetry_from_desc(poetry_forms_file):
    poem_form = {}

    with open(poetry_forms_file, 'r') as f:
        cur_header = None # latest header found in file

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()

            # Skip empty lines
            if len(line) == 0:
                continue

            if line[0].isalpha():
                # Found new header, add empty entry to dict
                cur_header = line
                poem_form[cur_header] = ([], [])

            else:
                # Found data, record it
                pair = line.split() # split on space

                data = poem_form[cur_header]                
                data[0].append(int(pair[0]))
                data[1].append(pair[1])

    return poem_form
```

EDIT:
The idea is you populate the dictionary as you know the information. You know that the layout of the file is a label, and the data that follows belongs to that label until another label is found.

This can also be made more efficient, because the forms the data can take are very limited. Either it is a label made of alphabetic characters, or data, which starts with a numeric digit. Therefore we can distinguish between the two by seeing if the line starts with an alphabetic character or not.

Because the value of each key in your dictionary `poem_form` has the format `([], [])`, so it is added with empty lists to the dictionary when we see a new label in the file. We also record that we are currently accumulating for that particular label (`cur_header`).

Whenever we see data, it is broken up and accumulated in whatever the current label is (`cur_label`).

For explanation regarding `with`, see this [link](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/). It can do a better job of explaining it than I can. Essentially, `with` is used when you have some block of text that has an operation done with it at the beginning and end of its use. Here I use it for `open`. Normally, you would have to open the file, and close it when you are done. In this function, when the `with` scope is exited, the file is automatically closed. To understand why that happens, see the linked article.

Comment: Holy hell that is amazing, works like a charm. Can I get the rationale behind this, as I've never seen with & as before.

Comment: This is an answer given without context to a question which could have been an assignment. How are people supposed to learn? As a teacher you should know better.

Comment: @FerdinandvanWyk You are correct. I do apologize to OP.